# Laravel 5.1 PHPUnit Tests for API using JSON

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-5

I just started working with Unit testing in Laravel 5.1 to test an API I'm building, and I can get PHPUnit to work fine with the ExampleTest.php, but when I create my own test, it fails every time.

Here is the response for my API endpoint `v1/conversations`:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "created_at": "2015-07-05",
      "updated_at": "2015-07-07"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "created_at": "2015-07-06",
      "updated_at": "2015-07-08"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is my ConversationsTest.php:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class ConversationsTest extends TestCase
{

    public function test_list_conversations()
    {
        $this->get('v1/conversations')->seeJson('data');
    }
}
```

But when I got to run my test, I get the following:

```
There was 1 error:

1) ConversationsTest::test_list_conversations
ErrorException: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase::seeJson() must be of the type array, string given
```

Isn't my API returning valid JSON data? Why can't Laravel's `seeJson` method interpret the response? I've tried to follow the [Laravel 5.1 Testing APIs documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/testing), but I'm clearly missing something...

Comment: It may be returning JSON, what the error is telling you though is you are passing a string into the `seeJson()` function when it only takes arrays.

Comment: It seems like the data is already formatted in a valid JSON format though... What is the best practice for changing the JSON formatted string into an array in this case?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this function but I'll write up an answer to hopefully explain better.

Answer (score 4):

The data returned by your endpoint is fine and should not be modified.  The error is simply telling you that you are passing a string into the function `seeJson('data');`

According to this here, https://github.com/laracasts/Integrated/wiki/Testing-APIs, you should be able to use it like so just to verify that some JSON is being returned...

```
$this->get('v1/conversations')->seeJson();
```

You can also pass in an array to this function to see if a certain part of the data exists...

```
$this->get('v1/conversations')->seeJson([
    'data' => 'some data',
]);
```

Though that will likely fail unless you pass in the entire array which is also being returned by your endpoint.

The only thing you can not do is pass in a string to this function as it wouldn't know what to do with a string.

Comment: Your answer doesn't work for me, because Laravel looks for an json array, but my Laravel app always returns an json object within an array.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.  Something is either json or it's not json.  There are no such things as "json objects" or "json arrays".

Comment: seeJson() checks the contain of the given array: ['checked' => 1] results in [checked: 1]. Laravel returns with response()->json(): [{checked: 1}]. Simply no pass.

Comment: Laravel doesn't return with that, you do depending on how your array is structured.  In this case, you simply wrap it in another array.  `..->seeJson([['checked' => 1]]);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class ConversationsTest extends TestCase
{

    public function test_list_conversations()
    {
        $this->get('v1/conversations')->seeJson(['data']);
    }
}
```